# Real simple algorithm to calculate number of requests in the last minute

Tags: java, count, request

My service is calling an other service and this other service throttle me based on the number of request sent during a hole minutes (doesn't matter how much per second, as long as there is < x request in the last minute)

I would like to display a **really really** rough estimate to my user of how much request has been made during the last minute.
It doesn't need to be accurate in anyway it is just a way for the user to see what roughly the numbers are

What would be the best, least memory demanding way of implementing such a counter ?

Comment: rpm (package manager) tag is not related here, please remove

Comment: do you mean number of requests sent in the last 60 seconds, or during the current minute, say 14:13, which may have started 10 seconds ago?

Comment: In the last 60 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

- maintain an `int[] requestCount = new int[60]`
- for each request: `requestCount[(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) % 60]++;`
- run a scheduled job every 1 second to reset the "stale" array position (61 seconds ago) back to 0
- to get the number of requests over the past 60 seconds: `IntStream.of(requestCount).sum();`

Note:

- this would not be thread safe. If you need thread safety you could use a `final AtomicInteger[]` array.
- this is not robust to clock changes etc.

The footprint should be fairly small.

Comment: wouldn't new int[60] and System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000 cause a problem here? it can be writting in postion 999 but the array only goes up until 59

Comment: @Johny19 you're right: should be `(millis / 1000) % 60`.

Comment: "run a scheduled job every 1 second to reset the "stale" array position (61 seconds ago) back to 0"
Does this means I have to traverse the array each 1 second to find the with entry is more than 60sec?

Comment: I suspect something like `requestCount[(millis / 1000) % 60 + 1] = 0` could do the trick - to be tested. Depends on how precise you want to be.

Comment: Will probably SO again (index 60). But yes I see your point I will try now